# Cassandra COPY From command hangs

Tags: cassandra, copy, cqlsh

I have a csv file, which I am trying to copy into Cassandra table. The copy command is able to insert the data from csv file to the table. but the command does not terminate at the end. instead, it gets stuck. I have to use keyboard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to kill it.

I want to know, what am I doing wrong!!

The steps are:
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.things (id uuid PRIMARY KEY, orders text,variable_name text,dataset text,code_list text, definition text, extended text);`

`cqlsh:test> COPY test.things FROM 'test.csv' WITH DELIMITER=',' AND HEADER=TRUE;`

```
Using 3 child processes
Starting copy of test.things with columns `[id, code_list, dataset, definition, extended, orders, variable_name].;

^C  --- I kill it here after it stuck for a pretty long time

Process FeedingProcess-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cqlshlib/copyutil.py", line 1282, in run
```

Comment: Everything looks fine. Try with a smaller file size and see if that works.